# Thinking quickly causes elevated mood

Tags: brain

I read this article: http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2006/09/060926171045.htm

It says, "When people are made to think quickly, they report feeling happier as a result. They also say they are more energetic, more creative, more powerful, and more self-assured. In short, they reported a whole set of experiences associated with being "manic."

"The results of our experiment suggest the intriguing possibility that even during moments when people feel stuck having depressed thoughts, interventions that accelerate the speed of such thoughts may serve to boost feelings of positive affect and energy."

Is there any biological basis for these claims or could the results be self-reporting biasness?

Comment: The original paper can be read here: [Manic Thinking: Independent Effects of Thought Speed and Thought Content
on Mood](https://psych.princeton.edu/psychology/research/pronin/pubs/2006FastThinking.pdf)